# Struts 2 WARNING: The default value expression contains "+" evaluated to 'nullnull'

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

I have a problem in my Struts 2 app.

I read the content of an iterator of an array.

The array elements are written out by an iterator:

```
<s:text name="#wApps.title"/>
```

The tag finds the correct element and evaluates it, but the resulting expression has a `+` character (e.g: the array element has value: `"Weather+ Free"`'), and it continues to evaluate it. Finally, it writes out value: `nullnull`.

How can I skip this second evaluation?

**Here is the log:**

```
Jun 18, 2013 5:29:40 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
WARNING: The first TextProvider in the ValueStack (rs.plusnet.android.market.AndroidMarket.UI.ListCategory) could not locate the message resource with key '**Weather+ Free**'
Jun 18, 2013 5:29:40 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
WARNING: The default value expression 'Weather+ Free' evaluated to '**nullnull**'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not struts, OGNL issue. OGNL doesn't evaluate expression twice, without special syntax that include subexpressions. However the "+" sign is an operator that evaluate the expression if you enter it without quotas.

Surround with quotas the value like this to prevent evaluation.

```
<s:set var="title" value="'Weather+ Free'"/>
```

or use the value in the body like this

```
<s:set var="title">Weather+ Free</s:set>
```

to check it

```
<s:property value="#title"/>
```

Also if the value is in the action property or any other scope the double evaluation should never occur.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Actually, initial situation should not be happened, it's only happens if you manually enter expression to the value attribute.

Comment: Thank's a lot! Solution <s:property value="#title"/> definitely solved my problem.